# Receiving error "Local collection types not allowed" while working with associative arrays

Tags: oracle, query, oracle-11g-r2, plsql, array

I have an input parameter with this format `'0,1,2,3,4'` , what I want to do is to declare an `array` with a variable size (by this I mean the input parameter might be like `'0,1'` , so the size is not fix), separate the items (0,1,2,3,4) and store them in an array of numbers. Below you can see what I've done so far :

```
declare

  v_input varchar2(400) := '0,1,2,3,4';

  type t_dep2custrel_type is table of number;
  t_dep2cust_rel t_dep2custrel_type;

begin

  select REGEXP_SUBSTR(v_input, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)
    into t_dep2cust_rel
    from dual
  CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(v_input, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL;

end;
```

and I'm receiving this error message :

```
"Local collection types not allowed in SQL statements"
```

I was wondering if you could help me find the problem and tell me whether there is a better way for doing this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT .. INTO` works only with queries that return a single row, and it can collect only scalar types. Your query returns multiple rows, and `BULK COLLECT INTO` should be used:

```
declare
  v_input varchar2(400) := '0,1,2,3,4';
  type t_dep2custrel_type is table of number;
  t_dep2cust_rel t_dep2custrel_type;
begin
  select REGEXP_SUBSTR(v_input, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)
    bulk collect into t_dep2cust_rel
    from dual
  CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(v_input, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL;
end;
/
```